# struts jQuery accordion: disallow user traversal

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, struts2, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm using the accordion in the struts jQuery plugin that has 3 accordion items inside.  Each of the accordion items has a button at the bottom, which runs a variation of this code: `$("#accordion").accordion('activate', 1);`.  I'm trying to come up with a way to either disable the accordion items so that accordion items only open by way of the activate code, or even somehow disallow the ability to open the accordion items by way of the click event on that item.

I've been researching this all morning, and have found that it seems to only be possible to disable the entire accordion (not just specific items), and the event option `$( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "event", 'mouseover' );` also is not working at all for me, although i seem to be able to change other options.

is there a better way to go about doing this??

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide

Comment: There was another question about this the other day. As far as I can tell, the jQueryUI Accordion widget has no intrinsic concept of any of the "folds" being disabled. There are simply no provisions for that in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up disabling the click event for the accordion items.
`$("#accordion li h3.ui-accordion-header").unbind("click");`